# Jquery addClass question

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me what this is doing? How should I refer to this in my html? What I want is to echo an error message in the html.

```
  $('#' + $field)
    .addClass('invalid')
    .siblings('.error')
      .text($message)
      .show();
```

Comment: Yes, I see you want to echo an error message. But when would you want ti? How do you want it to appear? where?

Comment: Reigel, I'd like to use the error message in a div below my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('#' + $field)  
  // finding an element that has the `id` of the string/object referred to by $field
    .addClass('invalid')
     // adding the class-name 'invalid' to this element
    .siblings('.error')
      // selecting the sibling element of class-name 'error'
      .text($message)
      // replacing the text of that sibling, if any, with the value represented by the variable '$message'
      .show();
        // showing/un-hiding that element.
```

You could use this by first assigning an element to `$field`, adding an element of class-name 'error' as a sibling of that element, and assigning a message to the `$message` variable.

---

**Edited** in response to OP's request for clarification (in comment).

As a fairly basic example:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        var $field = $('input[name=fieldName]').attr('id');
        var error = 'This field needs something else. Such as...';

        $('#'+$field).addClass('invalid').siblings('.error').text($message).show();
    }
);

<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="fieldName">This is a label:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldName" />

        <div class="error"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Rudimentary demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XeELs/)

Comment: David, thanks for the help and the explanation. I'm really new to JQ so most of what you're explaining isn't making it through. Whould you be able to show me how I need to use this in html? Like this?: `<div id="error"></div>`

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the error message will be echoed in the div?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, David. I can certainly digest this and finally understand how it all ties together.

Comment: @Jim, yeah, the error from validation (I assume you're using a plug-in to generate that) should be echoed to the closest div to the input. Probably via a `.each()` jQuery loop.

Comment: @David, thanks for the explanation. I just ran your code but didn't see anything echoed in the error div. Unfortunately, I have no idea why. :) In reaponse to the validation plugin, the errors are being generated by my PHP then echoed out for JQuery.

Comment: I'm going to start a new thread. I can't get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adds classname "invalid" (class="invalid") to selected field and then changes texts in siblings with class ".error" and shows them (removes display:none).

Comment: Thanks Māris, now I just need to figure out how to use them. :)